# Disable DetailsView from displaying the history input list

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

Is there a way to disable the display of the history input list in `DetailsView` edit mode?

[image]

Does any property need to be set on the fields?

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
    class="table_style"
    DataSourceID="SqlDatasource1" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False"
    DataKeyNames="SID,AreaName,FileName,UploadName,DeviceList,Serial"
    Width="80%" 
    BackColor="#DEBA84" 
    BorderColor="#DEBA84" 
    BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="3" 
    CellSpacing="2" 
    Font-Size="Large" 
    EnableViewState="false"
    >
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true" CancelText="取消" EditText="編輯" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SID" HeaderText="SID" SortExpression="SID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AreaName" HeaderText="地區名稱" SortExpression="AreaName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" SortExpression="FileName" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UploadName" HeaderText="UploadName" SortExpression="UploadName" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DeviceList" HeaderText="點位清單" SortExpression="DeviceList" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial" HeaderText="Serial" SortExpression="Serial"  Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ch_Date" HeaderText="上次更改時間" SortExpression="Ch_Date" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ch_User" HeaderText="上次更改人" SortExpression="Ch_User" ReadOnly="true" />

    </Fields>

</asp:DetailsView>
```